# dropdown and array name connection

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created 3 arrays with 3 unique names and each of them are preloaded with 5 different numbers.
I also created a dropdown list to have 3 array names included.
A second dropdown list I created includes "1,2,3,4,5" as array index.

A user selects the array name from the first drop down list, and select a number from the second dropdown list. I would like the value to be displayed based on the array name and index number the user picks. Anybody can help?

Comment: Post JavaScript in a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

```js
// assign array
const a = [2, 3, 5, 1, 2];
const b = [8, 4, 7, 6, 3];
const c = [9, 2, 8, 5, 1];

// get the value from dropdown list (html)
function myFunction() {
  const e = document.getElementById("myArray").value;
  const f = document.getElementById("myIndex").value;
  const d = parseInt(f); //convert it from string to int

  //use if statement to choose the correct array
  if (e == "a") {
    return (document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = a[d - 1]);
  }

  if (e == "b") {
    return (document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = b[d - 1]);
  }

  if (e == "c") {
    return (document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = c[d - 1]);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Array</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Select your Array:</p>
    <select id="myArray">
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
      <option value="c">c</option>
    </select>

    <p>Select your index:</p>
    <select id="myIndex">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

    <p id="p1"></p>
   
  </body>
</html>
```